# How can i correctly pass kwargs to RedirectView from django login to redirect to user profile?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am having a problem with having a user login and then redirect to the correct profile. Each user has a profile. Each profile has a dashboard. Using django's built-in login, I want to redirect the newly authenticated user to a url like this: example.com/profile/dashboard/.

I can't make this work because I cannot figure out how to pass the kwargs between the django login view and my detailview. In between, there is a redirectview. Can someone show me how to do this?

models.py

```
class Profile(TimeStamped, Slugged):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = (slugify(self.user.username))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profiles:detail', kwargs={'profile': self.slug})


class Dashboard(TimeStamped, Slugged):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profile.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dashboard, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = (slugify(self.uuid))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profiles:dashboard', kwargs={'profile': self.profile.slug,
                                                        'dashboard': self.slug})
```

views.py

```
class DashboardRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    permanent = False
    query_string = False
    pattern_name = 'profiles:dashboard'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dashboard = get_object_or_404(Dashboard, slug=kwargs['dashboard'])
        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles/home/', 
            DashboardRedirectView.as_view(), 
            name = 'home')
.........
```